# calling to a member function create() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp

I am facing some problem of **`calling to a member function create() on a non-object`**

please help me out,My code is :-

```
  <?php
     echo $form->create('Register', array('action' => 'register'));
     echo $form->input('username');
     echo $form->input('password');
     echo $form->input('cnfrmpassword', array('type' => 'password'));
     echo $form->submit();
     echo $form->end();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this.... You're missing `$this->` before the helper.

```
<?php
     echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'register'));
     echo $this->Form->input('username');
     echo $this->Form->input('password');
     echo $this->Form->input('cnfrmpassword', array('type' => 'password'));
     echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Comment: but now when i call the **register()**
it gives a error that call to a member function **save()** to a non-abject

`
<?
public function register() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'reg'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
            }
        }
    }
?>`