# PHP Error: "Call to member function create() on a non-object" Twilio code

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to get a version of [Twilio-PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) code working. I've hosted it and the Twilio library [here](http://tox.sinaiem.org/capetown.php).

An error is thrown on this line:

```
$response = $client->account->sms_messages->create($from,$number,$text);
```

It throws the error:

```
"Call to member function create() on a non-object"
```

I define `$from`, `$number`, and `$text` above as strings. The first two are verified Twilio `$text="Hi";`. The syntax of the call is cut and paste from the Quickstart section of that GitHub and so it is more likely that I am not using the code properly.

There wasn't enough explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035339/calling-to-a-member-function-create-on-a-non-object) question for me to understand the error message.

---

**Actual Code**

```
  <?php
 require './twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php';

 $AccountSid = X;
 $AuthToken =X;

 $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid,$AuthToken);
 $number = "1111";
 $text = "This is a test";
 $from = "2222";
 $response = $client->account->sms_smessages->create($from,$number,$text);
 ?>
```

Note: I replaced the real numbers and authorization tokens with dummies.

Comment: $response = $this->$client->account->sms_messages->create($from,$number $text);

Comment: sms_messages isn't an object. It's something else. an array, maybe?

Comment: Could you post the actual code here that you've written?

Comment: Another typo here `$from,$number $text`. you forgot `,` between `$number` and `$text`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar This wasn't a typo. It was a **strange** markdown problem (I would say a bug). It looked like : `$number ,$text` (note the space) but the markdown parser has eaten the `,`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your application works in detail and why it is not an object, but you should add a check:

```
if(!is_object($client->account->sms_messages)) {
    var_dump($client);
    die('something bad happened');
}

...
```

Comment: I know it's just a little hint, and the question might be deleted once anyway, but why the down-vote?

Comment: Agree- I'm not experienced in PHP and asking a genuine question after searching Twilios FAQs and SO without finding an answer I could understand that was helpful.

Comment: I upvoted your answer to make you feel a bit better :)

Comment: @mac389 I expect, that the `$client` object has not property `sms_messages` if the there are no messages. So you can use me check above to detect that

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = $client->account->sms_messages->create($from,$number,$text);
```

You had a typo in sms_messages

Comment: ARGH- you have better eyes than I do.

Comment: So, the error comes because PHP doesn't recognize what sms_smessages is, and certainly doesn't think it's a function or object?

Comment: yup, sms_smessages doesn't exist, so he can't do anything.

Comment: If this is the solution, can you please mark it as the solution?